# Calculating a Shannon index according to multiple treatments

Tags: r, bioinformatics, vegan

I counted plants in a trial with multiple treatments, I want to know if there is a difference between the treatment on the plant population. I want to create a new variable that has the Shannon index of each treatments. My data looks like this (with more rows and plant types):

```
 Treatment Rumex_acetosa Phleum_pratense Festuca Deschampsia_cespitosa Taraxacum_teg_Leontodon_…¹   
   <chr>             <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>                 <dbl>                      <dbl> 
 1 b                     0               0     100                     0                          2     
 2 d                     0               0     100                     0                          4     
 3 e                    16               0      62                    63                          0    
 4 g                    54              40       0                   100                          0     
 5 f                    99              39       0                   100                          1     
 6 a                    79               0       0                   100                          7     
 7 c                     0               0     100                     0                          0    
 8 f                   100              27       0                   100                          0    
 9 b                     0               0     100                    18                          4     
10 a                    18               0       0                    98                          9
```

```
## example data:
d <- structure(list(Treatment = c("1 b", "2 d", "3 e", "4 g", "5 f", 
"6 a", "7 c", "8 f", "9 b", "10 a"), Rumex_acetosa = c(0L, 0L, 
16L, 54L, 99L, 79L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 18L), Phleum_pratense = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 40L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 27L, 0L, 0L), Festuca = c(100L, 100L, 
62L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 100L, 0L), Deschampsia_cespitosa = c(0L, 
0L, 63L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 100L, 18L, 98L), Taraxacum_teg_Leontodon = c(2L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93MAN.png)

I tried to use the "diversity" function from the package vegan. But I can't find how to choose one specific row of the matrix with only the plant frequencies and do a loop for each row into a new variable.

I also tried with this example :

```
    n = population # type c(...)
    N = sum(population)
    p = n/N
    H = -sum(p*log(p))
    H
```

But I also have a problem of type for the population and to put it by treatment.

I am open for any advice, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

How about this (using your example data `d`)

```
library(vegan)

data.frame(Treatment = d$Treatment,
           Shannon =  diversity(x = d[, -1], ## exclude Treatment col
                                index = 'shannon'
                                )
           )
```

output:

```
   Treatment    Shannon
1        1 b 0.09650896
2        2 d 0.16302363
3        3 e 0.96818373
4        4 g 1.02312963
5        5 f 1.04837657
## ...
```

To add the diversity index to the existing data instead of creating a new dataframe:

```
cbind(d, Shannon =  diversity(x = d[, -1], index = 'shannon'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your data `d` this is the simplest way in **vegan** *if* you want to calculate diversity for each row.

```r
> diversity(d[,-1]) # -1 skips column 1 'Treatment'
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
0.09650896 0.16302363 0.96818373 1.02312963 1.04837657 0.82077479 0.00000000 
         8          9         10 
0.97551551 0.55739082 0.65928553
```

If you want to have diversity for a aggregated rows (*i.e.*, there are replicates of treatment and you want to summarize over rows), then you should first decide what you want to have since people seem to mean two very different things with this:

1. Mean of diversities by treatment: calculate diversities for each row and use something like `tapply(H, Treatment, mean)` for a vector of diversities `H`.
2. Mean of rows aggregated by treatment: use `vegan::diversity(d[,-1], groups=d$Treatment)` for your data `d`.

See discussion in https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/393.